# remove dynamically added panels

Tags: java, swing, java-7

In my previous questions I asked how to add dynamic `panels` and with the help of Stackoverflow members I could achieve my goal.

```
public class Reference {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            MainPanel main;  
            JButton addButton = new JButton();
            JButton removeButton = new JButton();
            List<SubPanel> subPanels = new ArrayList<SubPanel>();

            public static void main(String[] args) {
               new Reference();      
            }

            public Reference() {
                main = new MainPanel();
                frame.add(main);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(addButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
                frame.add(removeButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                           main.addSubPanel();
                           main.revalidate();
                        }
                    });        
            }
            private class SubPanel extends JPanel {         
               JTextField firstName = new JTextField(15);

            public SubPanel() {
                this.add(firstName);
           }

          public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
            public MainPanel() {
            }

            public void addSubPanel() {
                SubPanel panel = new SubPanel();           
                add(panel);
                subPanels.add(panel);
            }

          }  
        }
```

But the next problem that appears I cannot remove dynamically added `panels`. I tried many ways but without success.

I tried to use `removeSubPanel` method in `MainPanel`:

```
         public void removeSubPanel() {
           this.getParent().remove(SubPanel);
  }
```

And  for `removeButton` this code:

```
                  removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                           main.removeSubPanel();
                           main.revalidate();
                    }
                });
```

I cannot understand what is wrong. Maybe `removeButton` actionlistener is not correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your current code has variables named `SubPanel` and a class named `SubPanel`. This is really confusing. Please respect the java naming conventions and update that snippet.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 0):

In your MainPanel class:  `add(panel);`.  This adds the component referenced by the variable 'panel' to the "this" instance of MainPanel.

With the code `this.getParent().remove(SubPanel);` you try to remove a component from the parent of the instance of MainPanel.  (note too that the variable `SubPanel` is never defined in the code you presented)  You need to remove the component from the component that actually contains it.  Since the add method in your MainPanel class adds to `this`, you would want the remove method to remove from `this`:

```
public void removeSubPanel(final JComponent subPanel) {
   this.remove(subPanel);
}
```

You will also need to decide how to choose which of the components you want to remove when the button is clicked.  Perhaps the first one you stored in your list?

```
public void removeSubPanel() {
    // TODO: check that the list isn't empty first
   this.remove( subPanels.remove(0) );
}
```